# UiTableView not scrolling to bottom with static table swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I'm using a TableViewController with static tables cell and int not scrolling to the end. It scroll but not stay.

Comment: That's because you're not supposed to use a tableview with static cells. It's supposed to be done dynamically even if you'll only ever have a certain set of cells. If it's really always going to be static you should consider using a stack view inside of a scroll view.

Comment: Thanks for answer @DonovanKing. I Already solved the problem.

Comment: @DonovanKing ... erm... there is nothing stopping you using static cells in a table view. They are even supported by Storyboards. What is probably the problem here is that the table view is not constrained by auto layout properly.

Comment: @Fogmeister what you're saying is true, but doing so REALLY goes against best practices. Just because you can do something does not mean it's a good solution.

Comment: @DonovanKing not at all. They are really useful for creating layouts... http://www.oliverfoggin.com/using-a-static-uitableview-as-a-layout-device/

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm just saying what I've learned from people in the know. There's always multiple ways to do something, but there's really no reason to have the overhead of a tableview/controller object if it's never going to be dynamic.

Comment: @DonovanKing I don't know if I can say I'm "in the know". I've been developing apps for 8 years? But I think you're over thinking it. A lot of iOS apps are written (or were written) using static table views like this. There really isn't that much overhead. When it's static this way it's pretty much a scroll view with some views in it.

Comment: @Fogmeister that's fair. It is something however that I do encourage beginners to stay away from doing. I used to do swift education and usually when some one was having trouble setting up a static tableview they were approaching their problem from the wrong direction. I've also seen it cause bugs for people down the line, mostly because they didn't understand tableviews and how they work. All technicals aside...you are right the overhead is negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved setting all flags in Autoresizing.

[image]